# Multiple relationship issue in Orientdb-gremlin

Tags: orientdb, gremlin, gremlin-server

Let's create 3 vertices (with no relationship) [works fine]

```
graph.addVertex(label, "Master", "title", "master")
graph.addVertex(label, "Test", "title", 'abc')
graph.addVertex(label, "Test", "title", 'xyz')
```

Link master with abc [ works fine]

```
g.V().hasLabel("Master").addE("relation").to(g.V().has("Test","title",'abc'))
```

Link master with xyz [Fails]

```
g.V().hasLabel("Master").addE("relation").to(g.V().has("Test","title",'xyz'))
```

**ERROR**

```
Cannot UPDATE the record #59:3 because the version is not the latest. Probably you are updating an old record or it has been modified by another user (db=v2 your=v1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This exception happens because you're running in a Multi Version Control Check (MVCC) system and another thread/user has updated the record you're saving. For more information about this topic look at Concurrency.

Is this the case?

If so, you can check this [link](https://orientdb.com/docs/2.2.x/Troubleshooting-Java.html#oconcurrentmodificationexception-cannot-update-record-xy-in-storage-z-because-the-version-is-not-the-latest-probably-you-are-updating-an-old-record-or-it-has-been-modified-by-another-user-dbva-yourvb)

Hope it helps

Regards